# Crystal 2013: Missing parameter in select expert crystal 2013

Tags: crystal-reports

select expert is not populating my "date range" parameter that I created in field explorer. Can someone tell me what other methods I can use to add a date range into Crystal Report? Im using the 2013 software.

Comment: Can you show how you have created the parameter

Comment: Hello, I was able to add the parameter in the Command box. And it worked fine that way. It populated in under Parameter Fields under Field Explorer. As for the previous method, I right clicked on Parameter Fields under Field Explorer, and selected New. And entered the following; Name: Start Date, Type: DateTime, List of Values; Static. This method was where I was having issues trying to work the save the parameter.

Comment: Which method are you referring to